# using class to make discord bot for simple hello function

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

## the code i wrote works fine but when i call .hello on channel it gives me error

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"bot {self.user.display_name} started succesfully!!")

    @commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'hello {ctx.author.display_name}')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_command(self.hello)

intents= discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content= True
bot= Bot(command_prefix= '.', intents= intents)

tokn= 'MTE5MzU5NDM5ODI0NDYxODI3MA.GpvNRT.T1kNBXpP3egZ_g3a-8hOhYrmzzPIMtYGSOdPro'

bot.run(tokn)
```

the error it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped      
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: Bot.hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke       
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke      
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\risha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped      
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: Bot.hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

i run this code and it works. i use .help in chat it shows the hello
as a option but when i use .hello it dont give me replay and thwows the error above.
please guide me to the solution and tell me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your project was a little messy however with a little bit of clean-up it was possible to get the hello command running.

You attempted to create your bot inside of a class, this does not seem to be the way that discord.py recommends you create a bot with their library - see [discord.py/quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html).

Below is a modified version of your code that is more in line with the examples provided in the previously mentioned link.

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.message_content = True

token = ''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"bot {bot.user.display_name} started successfully!")

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'hello {ctx.author.display_name}')

bot.run(token)
```

The execution of the .hello and the .help commands can be seen below:

> **.hello**
>
> [image: Demonstration of the .hello command being executed]

> **.help**
>
> [image: Demonstration of the .help command being executed]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so to start, DO NOT post your token in public forums, this allows people to access your bot in public.

Here is your updated code with a break down:

```py
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

class Bot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.add_command(hello)

    
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"bot {self.user.display_name} started succesfully!!")

@commands.command() #move command outside class
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.display_name}')


intents= discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content= True
bot= Bot(command_prefix = '.', intents = intents)

tokn= 'TOKEN GOES HERE'

bot.run(tokn)
```